# How to end a 2 player turn based Game Center match when player quit out of trun

Tags: game-center, quit, gkturnbasedmatch

I have searched about everywhere and not found an anwer for this problem:

I have a 2 player game, turn based, via Game Center.

After a player has done his move, he has the ability in Game Center to quit the game. In my case, this automatically means the game has ended and the other player has won. However, I can not find a Game Centermethod to make this happen.

I can not use endMatchInTurnWithMatchData because it is not this players turn.

And if I try to use endMatchInTurnWithMatchData when it is the other player's turn, this isn't possible either, because there is no other player to send the endMatchInTurnWithMatchData to (because the other player already quit).

Is there anyone who knows the solution to this?

Thanks,
Martyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:playerQuitForMatch:` method of `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`. Here is an example code:

```
-(void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController: (GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController playerQuitForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [match.participants indexOfObject:match.currentParticipant];
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *next = [match.participants objectAtIndex:(currentIndex + 1)%[match.participants count]];
    [match participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit nextParticipants:@[next] turnTimeout:MAXFLOAT matchData:match.matchData completionHandler:nil];
    [next setMatchOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon];
    [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:match.matchData completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this only works if the player that quits is also the player whose turn it is.

Comment: What should I do, when the player quits OUT of turn?

Comment: Did this solution also work for quitting OUT of turn? May you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. What ended up working for me is to set yourself as the next participant when calling participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome.

Hope it helps!